# mod_rewrite same page with 2 urls?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if this is possible as it doesn't seem to be working at the moment.

This rule works fine currently:

```
RewriteRule ^games/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=games&console=$1 [NC,L]
```

But i also want it so when a user just goes to /games without the console part, it goes to index.php?page=games.

I tried just adding it like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteRule ^games/?$ /index.php?page=games[NC,L]
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want them to go to `/games` or to `/games/`?

Comment: I would like them to goto /games/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `?` character is in the wrong place. If you want your last parameter to be optional, this should do it for you.

```
RewriteRule ^games/?([^/\.]+)$ /index.php?page=games&console=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work It's only showing my page when i add a console after the /games/

Comment: Just try using `^games/?(.*)$` instead.